# Variable desde <a href="..."> a PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un código muy sencillo para poder obtener valores mediante el `<a href="...">` hacia una página en PHP:

**Código HTML:**

```
<a href="errors.php?value=502">Informar del problema</a>
```

**Código PHP** (`errors.php`):

```
<?php
$error = $_GET['value'];

echo $error;
```

Si lo ejecuto en `localhost` la página PHP simplemente está en blanco, no me muestra ningún `echo`.

Si subo los archivos en el servidor, al hacer click en el `<a href="...">` me descarga el documento PHP en vez de dirigirme a esa página con ese valor especificado.

¿Qué estoy dejando pasar para que ocurra esto y no me dé el valor (en este caso 502)?

**Actualización:**

Añado capturas del código para posibles dudas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Error del servidor</h1>
      <div class="error-code">502</div>
      <h2>Puerta de enlace incorrecta</h2>
      <p>(Bad Gateway)</p>
      <p class="lead">El servidor Web ha recibido una respuesta inválida mientras actuaba como puerta de enlace o servidor proxy.
        <!--Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.-->
      </p>
      <hr/>
      <p>Esto es lo que puedes hacer</p>
      <div class="help-actions">
        <a href="javascript:location.reload();">Recargar la página</a>
        <a href="javascript:history.back();">Vuelve a la página anterior</a>
        <a href="/">Vuelve al inicio</a>
        <a href="errors.php?value=502">Informar del problema</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Código PHP completo** (después de los comentarios):

```
<?php

$error = $_GET['value'];

echo $error;

echo 'Entra';

?>
```

Comment: Aparentemente lo estás haciendo correctamente. Yo me aseguraría de que esté bien referenciada la ruta al fichero `errors.php`. Prueba a cambiar el contenido del fichero por un simple `echo 'ENTRA'`. Si te sigue presentando una página en blanco es que el problema lo tienes en la ruta.

Comment: He probado a añadir ese `echo 'Entra'` y pasa lo siguiente:
-Si lo ejecuto en **Localhost (Firefox)**: Muestra la página completamente en blanco

-Si lo ejecuto en **Localhost (Google Chrome)**: Muestra todo el código php literalmente (es decir, mostrando el `<?php` hasta `?>`.

- Si lo ejecuto en el **Server (Firefox)**: Me descarga el archivo `errors.php`.

-Si lo ejecuto en el **Server (Google Chrome)**: Me descarga el archivo `errors.php`.

Comment: ¿Podrías subir todo el contenido de `errors.php` tal y como lo tienes ahora?

Comment: Y si miro el link en la url aparentemente coge esos valores `errors.php?value=502`, pero el código parece ser inútil. No consigo entender lo que está pasando.

Comment: Se trata de un comportamiento un tanto extraño. ¿Estás usando algún `framework` de **PHP** como Laravel?

Comment: He utilizado el PHPMailer, pero está ubicado en otra parte del servidor. Realmente no la estoy incluyendo en este código. Curiosamente el php me funciona correctamente, ya que consigue validarme captcha y enviarme un formulario por e-mail. Si lo necesitas, y crees que puede influir de algún modo a lo que está pasando, añado las rutas de los directorios y los archivos del servidor.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95854/discussion-between-phpmyguel-and-yuna-sch).

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a @phpMyGuel hemos concluído que el intérprete php de mi servidor no estaba en la carpeta en la que pretendía ejecutar `errors.php`por esa razón no funcionaba ninguna línea de código en php.

Así que la solución 1 podría ser modificar el `php.ini`de mi servidor;
O, solución 2, colocar los archivos `.php`en las carpetas en las que el intérprete del código funcione.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!